# Joomla 2.5 RokAjaxSearch Module has no method 'getLast'

Tags: ajax, methods, joomla, mootools, rokajaxsearch

I am almost finished with an customer Website and now I recognized that the RokAjaxSearch Module doesn't work anymore. It worked in the past!
I just made the last Joomla Update to 2.5.19, I looked also on the Roktheme homepage but did'nt found anything about my error. I also tried an Update of the modul.

The error message is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getLast'
```

Someone knows something about? i wont to modify the roksearch script cause the next Update will kill it.

Thanks for any help.
Peter

Comment: Looks like MooTools is not loading. Can you check if the library script is being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The Mootool Script gets loaded.

```
<script src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can access it also on this location.